# what is the exact syntax or specifications behind run_with_period c macro in redis

Tags: c, redis

I can't figure out the syntax of redis run_with_period macro. run_with_period(100) just passes 100 as 100ms to the if statement, but the following {} block calling three functions is what I am very confusing at. Is there any magic?

```c
/* Using the following macro you can run code inside serverCron() with the
 * specified period, specified in milliseconds.
 * The actual resolution depends on server.hz. */
#define run_with_period(_ms_) if ((_ms_ <= 1000/server.hz) || !(server.cronloops%((_ms_)/(1000/server.hz))))


run_with_period(100) {
    trackInstantaneousMetric(STATS_METRIC_COMMAND,server.stat_numcommands);
    trackInstantaneousMetric(STATS_METRIC_NET_INPUT,server.stat_net_input_bytes);
    trackInstantaneousMetric(STATS_METRIC_NET_OUTPUT,server.stat_net_output_bytes);
}
```

Comment: It's just `if ((100 <= 1000/server.hz) || !(server.cronloops%((100)/(1000/server.hz)))) { ... }`? Are you not aware of `if` syntax?

Comment: oh, i get it. Just simple text replacement, but to be honest spliting the if condition and its body seems a little wired in my point of view.

Comment: It's not a common practice, [but used sometimes](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/sys/sys/queue.h#L116).